# How do you run a command in VIM that outputs at cursor?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to be able to insert the results of -

```
date +"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:00"
```

at the cursor in vim. How would you run the above command in BASH but get the results and insert them directly at the cursor?

Right now I am running the command as -

```
:r!date +"\%y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"
```

But this inserts the contents on a new line. What is the correct method to evaluate a bash script AT the cursor?

```
Current Issue -
Date:
15-07-02 14:36:24

Expected Result -
Date: 15-07-02 14:36:24
```

Comment: Using visual selector with ! also does not work because it replaces the whole line and doesn't just insert on a single character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in `strftime()` does exactly what you want:

```
<C-r>=strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

To turn that into a mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> <key> strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

You can of course use whatever external command you need but it is important to keep in mind that the output of Unix commands usually ends with a newline character that needs to be removed in one way or another. The general solution is to strip that newline from the output before inserting it:

```
<C-r>=substitute(system("date +'%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"), "\n", "", "")
```

which is an ideal client for a mapping.

Reference:

```
:help strftime()
:help system()
:help substitute()
:help i_ctrl-r
:help "=
:help :map-expression
```

Comment: I got it working using C-f Thanks a ton! `inoremap <expr> <C-f> strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: I love using abbreviations for this! If you set `:ab idt <c-r>=strftime('%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')<cr>` then you can simply type "idt" while in insert mode.